# Setting a rotation matrix instead of Euler angles in tikz-3dplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-3dplot

In `tikz-3dplot`, I would like to use rotated coordinates by setting the according rotation matrix directly, instead of implicitly by Euler Z-Y-Z angles.

I already tried to modifiy the internal matrix elements with

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\raaeul}{0.5}
...
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rcceul}{0.33}
```

right before the `draw[tdplot_rotated_coords]`, but this had no effect at all.